# Click Anywhere Pop Up

Tags: popup

I'm trying to create a popup (new window) that appears when a person clicks anywhere on the page , but the problem is that my script creates a new tab for every click . I created a blogspot account just for test : http://faqetest123.blogspot.al/
what should I do for that ?
(example of a site that is using the popup that im trying to create is :atdhe.so)

Here is my code :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onclick=function()
 {
  window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
 }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `window.open()` function returns a reference to that window.  So you *should* be able to use that reference to navigate to a new URL at a later time.  Something like this:

```
var myPopup;
document.onclick=function()
{
    if (!myPopup) {
        myPopup = window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
    } else if (myPopup.closed) {
        myPopup = window.open('http://www.google.com');
    } else {
        myPopup.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    }
}
```

Note that this also attempts to check if the user has closed the pop-up and re-opens it.

---

**Edit:** Based on your comments below, it looks like I misunderstood.  In order to have the popup execute *once* and then not again, you can simply remove the event handler after processing it.  Something like this:

```
document.onclick=function()
{
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
    document.onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: thanks david but the problem is that a popup is still created for every click, i want just for the first click on the page. something like : atdhe.so . for a single visit the first click creates the popup. anyway thanks

Comment: @IsiTaho: Maybe I'm not understanding the question.  What is the exact behavior you're looking for?  You only want the popup to open *once* and then never again?

Comment: for the same person yes. only for the first click on the page to happen that .. the person can stay in the page for hours and the popup will not appear.  i dont know if im clear .

Comment: @IsiTaho: I've updated the answer.  If you don't want the popup to process after the first click then all you really need to do is remove the click handler.